# How to properly update and retrieve account info with Metamask

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, metamask

Im working on a button component that handles connecting a user to their Metamask wallet. The idea is that if a user’s wallet is not already connected, then the button will display ‘Connect wallet’, once they click on the button and connect their wallet the button’s text will change and instead show their account address '0x323..'.

The only thing i’m having trouble with so far is changing the state of the accounts variable and trying to retrieve an address from it. As of now all I can do is login to Metamask, but once connected the address isn't displayed because it didn't pick up that the state of the accounts variable changed. I’ve tried different variations in trying to update the accounts state, but nothing has seemed to work. Is there something I should change or include in my code?

```
let ethereum = window.ethereum;
let accounts = [];

// Renders a Button to handle the Metamask Connection
class WalletConnector extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // set state of account to empty if not connected to a wallet
      accounts: ''
    }
  }

  handleClick(){
    try{
      // prompts to connect to metamask
      ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });

      // * this did not work * 
      //this.setState({accounts: ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' })});
      
    }
    catch(error){
      // if user cancels metamask request 
      if (error.code === 4001){
        console.log('Metamask Connection Cancelled');
      }
      else {
        // if unable to requst account prompt to install metamask
        alert('Install Metamask to Connect');
      }
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}> 

          {/* if account is connected display address else ask to connect */}
          {this.state.accounts === '' ? 'Connect Wallet' : this.state.accounts} 

        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use async/await. `ethereum.request` would return an promise.

```
async function handleClick() {
  try {
    // prompts to connect to metamask
    await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });

    this.setState({
      accounts: await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" }),
    });
  } catch (error) {
    // if user cancels metamask request
    if (error.code === 4001) {
      console.log("Metamask Connection Cancelled");
    } else {
      // if unable to requst account prompt to install metamask
      alert("Install Metamask to Connect");
    }
  }
}
```